# Add letters only validation in a form Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to validate my name text box from the special character

I try this:-

```
public function rules() 
{
   [
       'full_name', 'match',
       'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
       'full_name' => 'full_name can only contain word characters'
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function rules() 
{
    return [
         'full_name', 'match',
         'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
         'message' => 'full_name can only contain word characters'
    ];
}
```

Refer [Yii2 Core Match Validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#match)